# How to add button prev and next in image slidershow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create an image grid, when to clicking an image; it shows this image, and I want to add more button to navigation quickly include: `previous`, `next` and `exit` button.

Currently, I only write javascript base on Jquery to click an image and show it.

```js
// Create a lightbox

var $lightbox = $("<div class='lightbox'></div>");
var $img = $("<img>");


$lightbox
 .append($img)

// Add lighbox to document

$('body').append($lightbox);


$('.portfolio-imgs a').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 // Get image link and description
 var src = $(this).children('img').attr("src");
 // Add data to lighbox

 $img.attr('src',src);

 // Show lightbox

 $lightbox.fadeIn('fast');

 $lightbox.click(function () {
  $lightbox.fadeOut('fast');
 });
});

var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    interval = setInterval(getNext, 2000); // milliseconds
    $('#next').on('click', getNext);
    $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.slideshow img').first();

    transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('.slideshow img:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.slideshow img').last();
    transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    $next.css('z-index', 2).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $curr.hide().css('z-index', 0);
        $next.css('z-index', 1);
    });

}
```

```css
.portfolio-imgs {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.portfolio-imgs img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;  
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-imgs {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.portfolio-imgs a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(215, 81, 107, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:200px;
}

.gallery-text:hover{
  opacity: 1;      
}

.gallery-text h3{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:100%;            
 }

.portfolio-imgs h3:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .portfolio-imgs a {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .portfolio-imgs img {
  margin: .25em .5em;
  }
  
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .portfolio-imgs a {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  
  .portfolio-imgs img {
    margin: .7em 1.5em;
  }

  .portfolio-imgs {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%;
  }

  .portfolio-imgs h3 {
    top: 40%; 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1020px){


  .portfolio-imgs {
    max-width: 80%;
  } 
}

/*Lighbox CSS*/


.lightbox{
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 20;
 padding-top: 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lightbox img{
 max-width: 80%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="portfolio-imgs">
  
  <a href="#"><img src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium/why-so-glum-square-dog-photography.jpg" alt="Cute Frenchie" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>BOOM!</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#"><img src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium/why-so-glum-square-dog-photography.jpg" alt="Cute Frenchie" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>BOOM!</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#"><img src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium/why-so-glum-square-dog-photography.jpg" alt="Cute Frenchie" />
  <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>BOOM!</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#"><img src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium/why-so-glum-square-dog-photography.jpg" alt="Cute Frenchie" />
  <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>BOOM!</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#"><img src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium/why-so-glum-square-dog-photography.jpg" alt="Cute Frenchie" />
  <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>BOOM!</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#"><img src="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium/why-so-glum-square-dog-photography.jpg" alt="Cute Frenchie" />
  <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>BOOM!</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add a span with correct class like here: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

or you can check this [example](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery)

Comment: Can you add example in my case? Thanks